# How to extract part of string using stringr?

Tags: r, stringr

I am learning about extracting string information using `stringr` library in R. Let's say I have a string `LC_Cars_20160601_01.hdf5.rds`. The numbers `01` before ".hdf5" indicate that it is for participant # 01. How can I extract this number? I have tried using `str_extract` but I don't know what should I provide in the `pattern` argument. Please guide.

Comment: You need to provide a regular expression. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html. For your purposes [0-9][0-9](?=[.]) would do.

Answer (score 2):

One option is using `gsub` to remove all the elements that are not required

```
gsub(".*\\d+_|\\..*$", "", str1)
#[1] "01"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "LC_Cars_20160601_01.hdf5.rds"
```